# Setting img content from blob is asyncronous, could be sync?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a blob with a img data.
I have a canvas where I show the img. 
I set the img.src and almost inmediately I see the image (on canvas).

I'm using the img.onload event.... to load the img on the canvas.
Is there any way to make a syncronic img-canvas asociation ?
Thanks

Comment: perhaps using callbacks

Comment: please include your code

Comment: For you to have access to the image data (so it can be drawn on the canvas) it needs to be loaded. The browser loads that image asynchronously, you can't tell the browser to freeze the whole webpage while the image loads. The answer is no, you can't. Why would you need such a thing?

Comment: Hi. I have these blobs saved at indexeDB. They are 'pure' img data and I simply was surprised I had to use the onload event....